# Generating a DTD from a multi-file RelaxNG schema

Tags: xml, dtd, file-conversion, relaxng

I have a RelaxNG schema that's broken into several `.rnc` files. I would like to be able to convert them into a DTD, but `trang` complains about my use of the `external` directive:

```
$ trang schema/text.rnc schema/text.dtd
[...]/schema/text.rnc:3:6: error: sorry, "externalRef" is not supported
[...]/schema/text.rnc:4:9: error: sorry, "externalRef" is not supported
[...]/grcxml/schema/text.rnc:6:15: error: sorry, "externalRef" is not supported
[...]/schema/text.rnc:3:6: error: sorry, "externalRef" is not supported
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.ContentType.ref(ContentType.java:138)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitRef(Analysis.java:232)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitRef(Analysis.java:78)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.edit.RefPattern.accept(RefPattern.java:9)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.analyzeContentType(Analysis.java:336)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitGroup(Analysis.java:216)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitGroup(Analysis.java:78)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.edit.GroupPattern.accept(GroupPattern.java:5)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.analyzeContentType(Analysis.java:336)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitElement(Analysis.java:118)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitElement(Analysis.java:78)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.edit.ElementPattern.accept(ElementPattern.java:9)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.analyzeContentType(Analysis.java:336)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitRef(Analysis.java:232)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitRef(Analysis.java:78)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.edit.RefPattern.accept(RefPattern.java:9)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.analyzeContentType(Analysis.java:336)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitDefine(Analysis.java:288)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitDefine(Analysis.java:78)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.edit.DefineComponent.accept(DefineComponent.java:39)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitContainer(Analysis.java:278)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitGrammar(Analysis.java:258)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.visitGrammar(Analysis.java:78)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.edit.GrammarPattern.accept(GrammarPattern.java:14)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis$Analyzer.analyzeContentType(Analysis.java:336)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.Analysis.<init>(Analysis.java:534)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output.dtd.DtdOutputFormat.output(DtdOutputFormat.java:22)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.translate.Driver.run(Driver.java:144)
        at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.translate.Driver.main(Driver.java:44)
```

Trang's ability to stuff an expressive schema like RelaxNG into a dim-bulb DTD seems miraculous enough that this roadblock surprises me. `external` includes are so nice for sharing definitions across schemata, I would hate to lose them. What would be the best way then to make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care that the DTD won't replicate the division into files of the source, you could use `jing` first:

```
$ jing -s source.rng > intermediate.rng
$ trang intermediate.rng final.dtd
```

The first step will combine everything into one file. The second will convert.

Comment: That seems like it will do the trick (though now it's complaining about my use of interleaving... ay yi yi). Thanks!

Comment: Is `-s` documented anywhere? I can't find it on the [Jing site](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/jing.html).

Comment: I recall seeing it somewhere a while ago but it might have been in a mailing list or something of the sort. The only immediate acknowledgment of its existence I get from `jing` is if I do `$ jing` without parameters. It is listed among the options but `jing` won't say what it does.

Comment: jing and trang are downright laconic in saying what they do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Trang to convert the .rnc compact schema to .rng, which should incorporate the external schemas into the main schema. Once you have a single .rng file, you might be able to convert that to a DTD.

See also https://code.google.com/p/jing-trang/issues/detail?id=51 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=264706 .

Comment: Helpful links, but @Louis summarized them nicely. Thanks!